# How to merge 2 WordPress sites?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 WordPress sites, A and B. Each of them has users and posts. Now, I want to merge these sites. Points to be noted-

1. A has 1000 users and 2000 posts. B has 500 users and 3000 posts.
2. There are some identical users. Say, Rahim and John have accounts on both sites. Rahim wrote 3 posts on A and 2 posts on B. Again, John wrote 0 posts on A and 5 posts on B. On A, user_id of Rahim is 3, on B it's 2. Similarly, John has different user_id on 2 sites.

Am I clear? Now, how can I proceed? I want to keep all the posts to original authors and unify duplicate users.

Comment: You are clear but I think your question is too board to be answered here, at least for me.

Comment: So, where should I ask? :(

Comment: Have you tried to export both databases and import them into a local test install? Does it work? What problems are you facing?

Comment: Had you tried native export/import process? In testing environment obviously, I wouldn't try to just run it live. :)

Comment: @Rarst it didn't work. there is an issue regarding primary key in wp_users table. say, both table has user ID 1. as they are primary keys and auto incremental, they can not be merged.

Comment: @mukto90 *they can not be merged* - theoretically *yes*, but what about your practical experience using native export/import? Was it failing with a failure notice, or saying to assign users to the posts?